# npgsql JSON Mapping - multiple different objects in JSONB column with EF Core

Tags: npgsql

I have a table in postgres containing a JSONB column.
This column contains a JSON object serialized from various C# types. This table also contains a column to select the C# type.
My entity model defines the JSON object as a string.
How to automatically deserialize into differing C# types?

BR Jochen

Comment: You're going to have to build that yourself. In other words, read the type column, resolve that into a CLR type, and then tell you JSON deserializer to deserialize the other column with that type.